# Nasdaq company list download with php

Tags: php

When downloading a list of companies in Nasdaq with Browser all works ok.

URL: https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NYSE&render=download

But when attempting the same with PHP after some time there will be an error "failed to open stream HTTP".

I found another question on the same topic: [HttpWebRequest Unable to download data from nasdaq.com but able from browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601454/httpwebrequest-unable-to-download-data-from-nasdaq-com-but-able-from-browsers)

Though not sure how to make this work in PHP. Attempted to use file_get_contents and curl with different set of headers but cannot make it work. Tested with same headers as in the similar question and also headers which my browser used in successful download.

Could anyone give me an example how to make this work in PHP? And is the problem in the headers at all?

Comment: This is my latest version: header('Host: www.nasdaq.com');
header('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8');
header('AcceptEncoding: gzip, deflate');
header('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1');
header('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');

$cont = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: `file_get_get_contents()` will ignore your headers. You should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) And define your header in cURL parameters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of curl request using either shell_exec or normal PHP curl library. I was comfortable with shell_exec that's why showing code this way.

```
$url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NYSE&render=download';
$output = shell_exec('curl -J -O -L -k -s "'. $url .'"');
```

Used options with curl are as follows, for more details about those options, you can do `man curl`:

```
-J, --remote-header-name
          (HTTP) This option tells the -O, --remote-name option to use the server-specified Content-Disposition filename instead of extracting a filename from the URL.

          There's no attempt to decode %-sequences (yet) in the provided file name, so this option may provide you with rather unexpected file names.
-k, --insecure
              (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bun‐
              dle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

              See this online resource for further details: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
-O, --remote-name
              Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)

              The remote file name to use for saving is extracted from the given URL, nothing else.

              Consequentially, the file will be saved in the current working directory. If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure  you  change  current  working  directory
              before you invoke curl with the -O, --remote-name flag!

              There is no URL decoding done on the file name. If it has %20 or other URL encoded parts of the name, they will end up as-is as file name.

              You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.
-L, --location
              (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make
-s, --silent
              Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you
              redirect it.
```

Comment: curl from command line at least returns something even if there is no options but still not sure why curl in PHP doesn't work. Tried following but still script just hangs:

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Host: www.nasdaq.com',
  'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8',
  'AcceptEncoding: gzip, deflate',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
 ));
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch)

Comment: OK. But it might have worked with curl command line. So did your purpose got solved with that or not.

Comment: Perhaps technically but not what I meant. What do you think, should I accept your response and open a new question which I would articulate better :)

Comment: It depends on you, I can't force you. If you are looking for output, then given answer suffice need. For increasing knowledge need to do little bit more with above code.